# How does this question "not appear to seek input and discussion from the community"?

Tags: discussion, meta, closed-questions, close-reasons, off-topic

Question in question: [Is it a good practice to write an answer to respond to another answer, rather than actually answer the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358733/260800)

It is closed for being off-topic with the reason:

> This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail. See also: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

I honestly don't understand why it doesn't even appear to seek input and discussion from the community. Can you help me see that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's a perfectly valid discussion and consider the closure as wrong.

I did cast a reopen vote, and hopefully it will be reopened with the help of other users.

Sadly I have no idea why the people closing it did it, only way to find out is asking them directly, better done in chat. At least two of them are regulars on Tavern, so you can do it in there. Good luck!